# import file with semicolon separation with file_fdw into postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy

I'm trying to link a table to the the content of file with semicolon separator.
first

```
CREATE EXTENSION file_fdw;
CREATE SERVER "semicolon_file" FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw;
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE file_semicolon_table ( civilite TEXT ,
        name TEXT ,
        surname TEXT)
SERVER "semicolon_file"
OPTIONS ( filename '/tmp/semicolon.csv',  DELIMITER ';');
```

And the semeicolon file looks like :

```
name;surname
paul;oreily
Alice;pira
Bob;tyres
```

I'm expecting a table like

| name | surname |
| --- | --- |
| paul | oreily |
| Alice | pira |
| Bob | tyres |

But instead I get :

| name | surname |
| --- | --- |
| name | surname |
| paul | oreily |
| Alice | pira |
| Bob | tyres |

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) tells me that I can't specify `HEADER` without `CSV` `FORMAT`. ([file_fdw is using the same syntax as COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/file-fdw.html))

Any clue ?

Comment: Use HEADER 'true' with FORMAT 'CSV'.  That will work with the data you showed us, as none of it needs either quoting or escaping.

Comment: sorry it doesn't compute. with `, CSV HEADER 'true');` and ` FORMAT 'csv' HEADER 'true');` or `, DELIMITER ';' FORMAT csv HEADER 'true'`  I always get a `syntax error`

Comment: Your middle one almost had it, you were missing a comma.  `... (filename '/tmp/semicolon.csv',  FORMAT 'csv', HEADER 'true', DELIMITER ';')`

Comment: Thank you very much ! That was the answer :)